# UnInstall Shortcut start menu in Wix bootstrapper project not removing the program from control panel

Tags: c#, .net, wix, wix3.11, windows-application-packaging

I am creating my PC desktop application installer using Wix. first I am creating MSI package and then using Wix bootstrapper to create exe file. Everything is working fine except Uninstall option in the start menu shortcut. There is an option is coming to uninstall the product , but it is not completely uninstall my product from control panel. Even when i uninstall using uninstall shortcut, the product is still available in the control panel. I think the problem is with bootstrapper project.

For the setting the uninstaller, I have done the below settings in the MSI bundle creation project.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="539ec72a-d8fa-455a-9e2c-4586c05b3dfb">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
             Name="WBidMax5"
           Description="Wbid Client App"
            Target="[#WBid.WBidClient.Main.exe]"
                  WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY"/>
          <Shortcut Id="Shortcut1" Name="Uninstall Wbid" Description="Uninstall WBid" Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe" Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\WBidMax5" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

Doing so creating the uninstall short cut in start menu.  But how can I completely remove the application from control panel also using Wix bootstrapper project?
I know some old topics are there , but there were no correct answer.

Comment: Should you add an uninstall shortcut? I cannot find a single uninstall shortcut in my start menu. I would expect people to use the control panel to uninstall programs.

Comment: Yes. Adding the above code will create Uninstall shortcut on the start menu. For the MSI installer , it will uninstall the program from control panel also. But exe file created 
 by bootstrapper project is not completely removing the applicaiton from control panel using the uninstall shortcut

Comment: I understand that your creates a uninstall shortcut. My point is why are you doing that? While this was somewhat common in the win95 era, the modern convention is to use the control-panel for uninstallation. Therefore no uninstall shortcut is necessary, So why do you want an uninstall shortcut?

Comment: Its just easy for the user to uninstall the product from start menu itself. Also I am upgrading the old install schield installer to wix installer. Old installer have this uninstall short cut  and users are using this shortcut to uninstall it. If bootstrapper have such functionality , I can add that also for the users.